# Meaning of every other day/week

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the meaning of “every other time”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12690/what-is-the-meaning-of-every-other-time)

What does the phrase *every other day/week* mean? I got some hint from [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12690/what-is-the-meaning-of-every-other-time). But, it is still not clear to me what is the need to add *other*.

Can we also say *every alternative day/week*?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*Every day* means: day1, day2, day3, day4, day5, etc., i.e. every single day, not skipping any.

*Every other day* means: day1, day3, day5, day7, etc., i.e. skipping every second day - one day on, one day off, and so on.

Comment: What about the answer in the link in my question (I corrected it)?

Comment: @Stat-R: What about it? It basically says the same thing, a bit less explicitly

Comment: Oh.Ya..I did not understand it properly. Actually, I had the notion that it would be one day on and one day off. But wanted clarifation. Thanks for making it explicit.

Comment: Technicality: In context, the phrase might also mean every day other than some specified day, like "On Fridays I eat fish; every other day I eat meat."

Answer (score 7):

The word *other*, in this case, is used to mean *alternate*. It is similar to saying "every *odd* week" or "every *even* week", only it doesn't matter what number week it is, it only matters that it's every *second* one.

Saying "every week" and saying "every other week" are not equivalent; it has nothing to do with rules of grammar, only with the fact that it's every second week.